# Is it possible to run a batch file as part of the Run command (i.e. F5)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'd like to execute a batch file when I run the solution which will prepare the environment that I'm deploying to. I want this to run first thing when I hit F5 before anything else happens. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project's property pages, under *Debugging* tab, set the proper value for *Command* option. Default value is `$(TargetPath)`, which will run the output executable. Just specify your batch file there.

You will have to run the executable on your own in this case. I suggest passing `$(TargetPath)` as a parameter to your batch script and then executing the parameter.